# Criar um algoritmo para identificar dias de semanas em c++

Tags: c++

Como crair um algoritmo para identificar dia da semana(numerados de 1 a 7) e dia de semana,fim de semana, ou um dia  invalido?

Comment: procure elaborar melhor suas dúvidas, assim parece que você está passando um exercício pra comunidade do site.

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução simples usando o `switch`

```
int main() {
    int dia;

    printf("Entre com um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &dia);

    system("cls");

    switch(dia) {
        case 1: printf("Segunda"); break;
        case 2: printf("Terça"); break;
        case 3: printf("Quarta"); break;
        case 4: printf("Quinta"); break;
        case 5: printf("Sexta"); break;
        case 6: printf("Sábado"); break;
        case 7: printf("Domingo"); break;
        default: printf("Numero invalido");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser obter o dia da semana através de uma data `05/03/2017` terá que fazer os cálculos referente ao ano, mês e dia.

Veja o algoritmo que adaptei para retorna os nomes em português:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *wd(int year, int month, int day)
{
  static const char *weekdayname[] =
  {
    "Segunda",
    "Terça",
    "Quarta",
    "Quinta",
    "Sexta",
    "Sábado",
    "Domingo"
  };

  size_t JND =                                                     \
          day                                                      \
        + ((153 * (month + 12 * ((14 - month) / 12) - 3) + 2) / 5) \
        + (365 * (year + 4800 - ((14 - month) / 12)))              \
        + ((year + 4800 - ((14 - month) / 12)) / 4)                \
        - ((year + 4800 - ((14 - month) / 12)) / 100)              \
        + ((year + 4800 - ((14 - month) / 12)) / 400)              \
        - 32045;

  return weekdayname[JND % 7];
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d/%02d/%02d: %s", 2017, 3, 5, wd(2017, 3, 5));

    return 0;
}
```

Saída

> 2017/03/05: Domingo

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6057429/5429980